# Lavavel 8 is not uploading pdf files that are generated from mpdf

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I am using Laravel-8 for file upload.
My code is below:
View:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label >Client Receipt</label>
    <label class="file">
      <input type="file" id="file" name="file"  aria-label="File browser example">
     <span class="file-custom"></span>
    </label>
 </div>
</div>
```

Controller :

```
      $request->validate([
        'file' => 'required|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg,csv,txt,xlx,xls,pdf|max:2048'

        ]);

        

        if($request->file()) {
         $name = time().'_'.$test_no.preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $request->file('file')- 
  >getClientOriginalName());

            $filePath = $request->file('file')->storeAs('applicationFiles', $name, 'public');


$fileLocation=$name;
        }
        else {
        $fileLocation='#';  
            
        }
```

It works fine. But when I use the pdf file which is generated from mpdf or this type of pdf generator then It can't upload the file.
What could be the problem?
I need suggestions.

Comment: "It can't upload the file" - what happens instead? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want the mpdf generated files to be stored on the server.

Read the mPDF documentation for the Output() function.

https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/output.html

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('Hello World');

// Saves file on the server as 'filename.pdf'
$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf', \Mpdf\Output\Destination::FILE);
```

Values:

```
\Mpdf\Output\Destination::INLINE, or "I"
```

send the file inline to the browser. The plug-in is used if available. The name given by $filename is used when one selects the “Save as” option on the link generating the PDF.

```
\Mpdf\Output\Destination::DOWNLOAD, or "D"
```

send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by $filename.

```
\Mpdf\Output\Destination::FILE, or "F"
```

**save to a local file with the name given by $filename *(may include a path)*.**

```
\Mpdf\Output\Destination::STRING_RETURN, or "S"
```

return the document as a string. $filename is ignored.

Comment: My question was not Mpdf generated files stored on the server. I have generated a pay slip by Mpdf. Then I upload the pay slip by Laravel form. That time file was not uploaded. But it successfully uploads files when I use the scan documents.